# Handling jQuery Form Validation on Value Populated in from DropMenu Selection

Tags: jquery

I have a form I want to run some validation on. The problem I'm running into seems to be that if I manually type in a value, my code picks it up. If however I populate in a value from, say, a drop-menu click, my code doesn't register the field I dropped the value into as having a value. How can I handle both scenarios? In other words, if there's a value in the form field, it should be valid. This is the code I have presently (I'm checking 3 different form fields (#selection, #schedule, #repeat-every) to make sure values exist before a "save" button is enabled. Note that the first value must exist, and one of the other two needs to have a value in order for the save button to be enabled. I think the problem is related to what actually causes `change()` to run:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.save-button').attr('disabled', true);
  $('#selection, #schedule, #repeat-every').change(function() {
    const selectionVal = $('#selection').val();
    const scheduleVal = $('#schedule').val();
    const repeatEveryVal = $('#repeat-every').val();
    if (selectionVal == "" || (scheduleVal == "" && repeatEveryVal == "")) {
      $('.save-button').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('.save-button').attr('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Job Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="job-name form-control" id="selection">
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="schedule-div">
  <div><label for="meeting-time">Schedule</label></div>
  <input type="datetime-local" class="job-schedule form-control" id="schedule">
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="repeat-every-div">
  <label>Repeat Every</label>
  <input type="text" class="job-repeat-every form-control" data-toggle="modal" id="repeat-every" data-target="#scheduleModal">
</div>

    <input type="button" class="save-button" value="save" />
```

Comment: Please explain how to reproduce your issue. I would personally use on("input") for the text fields

Comment: `change()` doesn't run unless I manually click in and out of the input field to enter a value. If I populate in a value from a drop-menu selection - without clicking within the field, `change()`does not fire, so the evaluation isn't run.